# Transparent lines in ThreeJS

Tags: graphics, three.js

It doesn't look like LineBasicMaterial has any way that I can assign an alpha to it. But I would really like transparent lines. How do I do that? The whole line will have the same transparency, I guess that means it's a constant alpha?

Comment: What have you tried? Let's see your code. `LineBasicMaterial` does have the ability for transparency. Have you [read the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mathut#api/en/materials/Material.opacity)?

Comment: Y'know, when I was reading the docs, I looked for alpha and transparency. I did not search for opacity, and certainly not in all the inherited classes. I'm going to try that out. You're welcome to post this as an answer, otherwise I can set up a js fiddle or something with a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/larrybo/pen/BaPMgJw) demonstrating opacity in lines. Note that you must include `transparency: true` in the material properties, otherwise three.js will not consider opacity in its rendering formula.

Thank you [@Marquizzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2608515/marquizzo) for kindly pointing me to this property, it's exactly what I was looking for.